# Uncaught ReferenceError: ufa is not defined using Google visualization API

Tags: api, visualization

I have encountered in which the visualization chart doesn't show due to this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: ufa is not defined

This is the link where js called is located. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your webpage calls to `jsapi` and `google.load()` once. Qouted below details from [**Google Developer's Site**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#offline)

> You may be using the Google Loader incorrectly.
>
> Only load jsapi once. No matter how many charts you have on your web page, you should have one and only one call like this:
>
> `<script type="text/javascript"`
>   `src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> // Do this ONCE.`
>
> Ideally, call `google.load` only once, with all the packages you'll need
>   for your web page.

**Do the loading of multiple packages like below,**

```
 <script>
       google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart", "timeline"]});
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you Bob. This leads me to search for multiple declaration on my templates. This works!